# regex help in notepad++ marking embedded values and copying into a new list

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large text file with numerous lines containing data like below.

```
205=1<SOH>55=ES<SOH>48=17875701615154475972<SOH>207=CME<SOH>100=XNYM<SOH>16552=1
```

205=155=6A48=17875736456456445774207=CME100=XNYM16552=1

I would like to extract all of the values that are after the "48=" and before the ASCII code 01 delimiter AND the same for the value after "55=" and paste them into a new file:

```
ES|17875701615154475972
6A|17875736456456445774
```

They aren't all 20 characters in length, so I would need to do a regex search to mark them all - can you help me with the right regex expression to use and how to copy the identified values out of notepad++?

Comment: Could you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a replacement on the whole file to leave only the targets:

```
Find: ^.*\b48=(\d+).*
Repl: $1
```

Then <kbd>ctrl+a</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> and paste into a new file.

---

To answer the question in the comment about capturing "CME" and allowing both "55" and "48" as markers:

```
Find: ^.*?(?:48|55)=([\w;]+).*?=([A-Z]+).*
Repl: $2|$1
```

Comment: What would the regex have to be to ALSO find the value of tag 207 IN ADDITION to tag 48?  So the output would be:
CME|178757016134154475945

Comment: I tried this. - ^.*\b55=(\w+).*\b48=(\d+).* - but the issue I found was the values after 55= can also include characters like colons, so what options can I supply the regex to include letters, digits and characters?  /w did not catch the colons...

Answer (score 0):

The following will match and create a group for the digits. `<SOH>48=(\d*)<SOH>`

However, what you probably want is a global search/replace that finds the numbers and rewrites the file. Try

Find: `.*<SOH>48=(\d*)<SOH>.*`
Replace: `\1`

Of course remember to check the Regular Expression box or it won't work at all.